# Crystal Reports - Hide page header if there in no record on a page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How to hide a page header if there is no record(details section) on last page. Page header must be shown on last page if there is some data on last page otherwise hide the page header.

Formaula `pagenumber = totalpagecount` won't work as it will always suppress the last page's header.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put this formula in a suppressed field in the detail section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished := OnLastRecord
```

And make this the Suppress formula in the page header:

```
Global BooleanVar finished
```

- Before `finished` is initialized the page header will show.
- Once you print a detail record it'll be set to `false`.
- When you finally reach the last detail section, `finished` is set to `true`.
- If you happen to reach another page header, `finished` is still `true`, and Crystal will suppress the header.

It's an interesting problem. I've encountered this behavior before but never tried to solve it. I think you need to use a variable because in a page header, the usual options like `Next()` and `OnLastRecord` can't distinguish between having one more record to print and having no more records to print. I think running totals would have the same problem – the values would be the same on a page with one more record to print, and on a page with no records to print.

Comment: Superb , thats what i was looking for, and a post from 2011 gives a hint.

Comment: It's working great if you have multiple records but if you have only one record then it won't print page header...

Comment: I tried this and it hide the page header on page which has no record in detail section but it also hide last record from detail section in mine. So it display wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

I've found better, and working solution to this answer (just tweaked Noa's code a bit):

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished := OnLastRecord AND NOT OnFirstRecord
```

and it works, even if details contains only one row.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to adapt [Crystal Reports: Display a Message When Report Has No Data](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2007/08/28/crystal-reports-display-a-message-when-report-has-no-data/) to meet your needs.