# Suppress Page header when there is no data in Details sections

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using a datatable to load the data for the crystal report. Based on the data filtered by the user in the DataGridview and clicking on Print will display the filtered data in Report.

All is fine.I have done this.When there is no data in the Details section I am suppressing it using the below formula in the suppress.

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;

If OnLastRecord then PageofLastField = PageNumber;
```

In the header section when there is no data in Details section supress page header.Below is the formula used.

(Reference [Crystal Reports - Suppress a Page Header if the page has 0 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294027/crystal-reports-suppress-a-page-header-if-the-page-has-0-records))

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;

PageofLastField := PageofLastField;

if pageofLastfield <> 0 and PageNumber > PageofLastField
  THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
```

Below is the image of the crystal report.[image]

When I click PRINT button in the front end. When there is no data in Details section the Page header is displayed.

Below image is the Second page of the report where there are no records and summary is displayed.

[image]

If in the header section if I use the below formula

```
OnLastRecord AND Count({PaymentReportTable.InvID}) <> 1
```

In the Second Page even if the records are displayed Pageheader is not displayed.I understand it becos the formula says it all.

[image]

I have created around 12 Crystal reports and I am facing the same problem in all of them.

Please advice.

Comment: I have also tried ...Pagenumber<>1 and IsNull({PaymentReportTable.InvID}). If on second page InvID is not null it is displaying the header.But when there is no data still the header is displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980282/crystal-reports-hide-page-header-if-there-in-no-record-on-a-page

Answer (score 0):

I read your question. just inform me what happen when you not suppress.

I think your footer evaluate because of it has the value.

are you try `OnLastRecord or {GROUP FIELD NAME} <> Next({GROUP FIELD NAME})` this condition as your reference link.

Comment: Hi Mate,

If I dont suppress i get a table with the PageHeader on it and the Report footer details get overlapped with it.In simple workds there is table with Column headers and the report footer details are displayed on it.I have tries the formula if mentioned.But still the same problem.InFact i didn't understand what this formula does exactly.

Comment: And one more point is I am not using any group field in the report.I am just sending all the data from Datagridview to the report using Dataset.

Comment: When I used the formula posted by you(which is in the reference).Last row in the datagridview is not printed in the report.Or else all fine.